# Chef multiple conditions

Tags: windows, powershell, chef-infra

I have the following chef/powershell code:

```
# Configure Registry Keys
powershell_script 'Configure Registry Keys' do
    code <<-EOH

    # Set the default location for data files
    Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\\Software\\Microsoft\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\\MSSQLServer" -Name DefaultData -Value "D:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\\MSSQL\\DATA"

    # Set the default location for log files
    Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\\Software\\Microsoft\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\\MSSQLServer" -Name DefaultLog -Value "L:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\\MSSQL\\DATA"

    # Set the default location for backup files
    Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\\Software\\Microsoft\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\\MSSQLServer" -Name BackupDirectory -Value "B:\\sqlbackups"

    restart-service *sql* -force
    EOH
    guard_interpreter :powershell_script
    not_if "(Get-ItemProperty \"HKLM:\\Software\\Microsoft\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\\MSSQLServer\").PSObject.Properties.Name -contains \"DefaultData\""
    not_if "(Get-ItemProperty \"HKLM:\\Software\\Microsoft\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\\MSSQLServer\").PSObject.Properties.Name -contains \"DefaultLog\""
    not_if "(Get-ItemProperty \"HKLM:\\Software\\Microsoft\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\\MSSQLServer\").PSObject.Properties.Name -contains \"BackupDirectory\""
 end
```

However when I run it it fails to run:

```
 * powershell_script[Configure Registry Keys] action run (skipped due to not_if)
```

That's because one of the keys exists but the other two do not.

What I'd like to happen is for the keys to get created if ANY of them don't exist. It seems like with multiple not_ifs if any of them result in a $true then it skipped.

What I want is that if any of them return $false then execute.

I tried to switch my not_if to an only_if but that seems to have the same problem (just in reverse)

So how can I concatenate multiple not_if or only_if statements together so that they all have to return $false (or all $true - depending on if only_if is being used)

Hopefully this makes sense but please let me know if it doesn't :)

Comment: You should [read the documentation](https://docs.chef.io/resource_powershell_script.html#guards)

Comment: @theincorrigible1 I'm not sure how that is helpful? (I had read that by the way). I don't even see any indication in the above documentation that multiple "not_if" or "only_if" are supported. (I found that out elsewhere - via google search.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a test for any of them not existing:

```
not_if "$Name=(Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\\Software\\Microsoft\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\\MSSQLServer').PSObject.Properties.Name; $Name -contains 'DefaultData' -and $Name -contains 'DefaultLog' -and $Name -contains 'BackupDirectory'"
```

Comment: That does work (thank you!). In this case you were able to consolidate everything into a single powershell statement but in a situation where that's not possible (due to complexity of the conditions) is it possible to somehow accomplish this same result with multiple "not_if" (or "only_if"s)?

Comment: @Brad I'm not sure, I only glanced at the documentation to help you out.  If this helped you, please mark it as an answer for future searchers.

Comment: The answer provided solves this exact problem (so I *do* appreciate the answer) but doesn't answer the underlying question which is how do you (or maybe can you) concatenate multiple only_if or not_if statements in chef?

In this instance you were able write a "one-liner" to put in a single not_if but what if that wasn't possible because I had to check multiple complex conditions that wouldn't work in a one-liner.

Comment: If you have multiple complex conditions, it sounds like you're over-complicating the scope of your problem @Brad It doesn't look like Chef supports what you're attempting to do